# C# Composite Event

Tags: c#, user-controls, compact-framework

I am creating a `UserControl` with a other controls inside. I want to create some form of "composite" event to provide for the forms using the `UserControl`.

For example: I have a lot of panels inside of this `UserControl`. I am creating one `EventHandler` inside the `UserControl` to handle all `MouseDown` events of these panels. In the end I want to make all MouseDown events on the `UserControl` to appear as just `MouseDown` on the parent.

I could create a new Event like `MousePressed` on this `UserControl`, but I would rather go with the already existing name `MouseDown`. How do I have  to declare this new event in order to "hide" the other `MouseDown` Event that already exists?

I hope I could explain my question enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this may show you how to do what you're looking for:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5249/How-to-override-parent-class-event-method-with-you

Answer (score 1):

Register all events needed in the `UserControl` (except the event of the `UserControl` itself, this will be the one needed to register on the parent form).

Most events seem to have a method used to call them. You can call this method starting with "On". For example: `OnMousePressed`

```
// You can register all MouseDown Events you need in one EventHandler.
private void Item_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Call this method to call the UserControls event.
    this.OnMouseDown(e); 

    // Register to the UserControl's MouseDown event where you want to catch it.
}
```